# Question about acummulation of nonlinear phase of laser pulse propagating in matter?

Tags: laser, non-linear-optics

The nonlinear phase or B-integral depends on the peak power $P_p$ and $n_2$.

Is it the same for 1Hz laser and for 100MHz assuming they have same pulse energy ?

$P_p=E_{pulse}/\tau/Area$

$B = 2\pi/\lambda\int_0^z P_pn_2dz$

Does self-focusing start for 200MHz earlier increasing the Energy of the laser per pulse? Does self-focusing depend on the peak power or the average power ?

Answer (score 1):

The B-integral depends only on peak power and not average power, as you state in your question. The peak power from a laser or amplifier can be approximated by (assuming a Gaussian pulse shape):
\begin{equation}
P_{\rm{peak}}\approx0.94\frac{P_{\rm{average}}}{f_{\rm{rep}}}\frac{1}{\tau_{\rm{pulse}}}.
\end{equation}
For a constant pulse energy the repetition rate and average power scale proportionally, so the peak power will be constant if the pulse duration doesn't change. This means that the accumulated nonlinear phase will stay the same as well. This neglects complications from amplifier design which will arise when trying to scale repetition rate without adjusting pulse energy.

Following this line of reasoning, self-focusing from the Kerr nonlinearity will be independent of repetition rate (assuming a constant pulse energy). However, *thermal lensing* will have a larger effect for higher repetition rates for a given pulse energy (assuming no additional effort to cool the gain medium is made) because the average power is being increased.

Comment: Why experimentally high repetition lasers have problem propagating long distances for same otherwise pulse energies and parameters?           Does self focusing depend on the average power ?

Comment: This question needs more specifics and is too general, I think. Propagating long distances in what (e.g., atmosphere, optical fibre, or crystalline gain medium), and under what conditions? Self-focusing depends only on the pulse energy which can, within limits of careful design, be independent of repetition rate. More generally speaking, thermal lensing can scale with repetition rate for constant pulse energy as it is related to average power. Do you mean thermal lensing or self focusing?

Comment: For clarity: Self-focusing is an intensity dependent effect determined by the Kerr nonlinearity of the propagation medium. If the pulse energy and duration are the same, then the peak intensity is the same regardless of repetition rate, and so self-focusing is independent of repetition rate in this case. However, in the same case average power is scaled by scaling the repetition rate, which means that the propagation medium will get hotter. This will increase thermal lensing, but this is not the same as self-focusing and the two terms are not interchangeable.